# Getting MemoryError making hexagonal lattice over polygon in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, numpy, memoryerror

I am creating a hexagonal lattice that I will then use to create Thiessen Polygons. We are required to make a lattice first. I can't figure out how to get rid of the MemoryError that looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shehn\Documents\ArcGIS\PyScripts\lab6ed.py", line 31, in 
    sh.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(p))
MemoryError

Failed to execute (Hex1).

Here is the code I'm using

```
    # Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Local variables:
lyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
b = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr)
file = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
spacing = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
if(not file.endswith(".shp")) : file += ".shp"
e = b.getExtent()

xamin = e.XMin
yamin = e.YMin
xamax = e.XMax
yamax = e.YMax
deltaX = xamax - xamin
deltaY = yamax - yamin
half = spacing / 2

numpx = int(deltaX / spacing) + 2
numpy = int(deltaY / spacing) + 2

p = arcpy.Point() # Create a "Point" object
sh = []

for j in range(numpy):
    p.Y = yamin + spacing * j
    for i in range(numpx):
        p.X = xamin + spacing * i
        if (j % 4 == 1 or j % 4 == 2) : p.X += half
        sh.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(p))

temp = "C:\\Temp\\t.shp"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sh, temp) # Create a temp shape file

arcpy.Clip_analysis(temp, lyr, file, "")
arcpy.Delete_management(temp)
# Create a layer from the shape file and add it to the map
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(file)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)

# Delete unused objects
del layer
del df
del mxd
```

Comment: Try printing (and presenting) the values of the three parameters that you are getting from your tool dialog, and then hardwire them while testing.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: I think you do not need to store values in a list, ie *sh*. You can create a feature class (shp) and use insert cursor to add each point. Your script is looking fine but as @PolyGeo mentioned, your inputs or the extent processed might be the issue.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a look at array object and utilise add method which creates multipoint but the it is easy to make it single part afterwards.

Comment: @fatih_dur, thank you for the suggestion, I am definitely looking into my inputs

Comment: Is your input covering a large area? Have you tested this script before and was successful?

Comment: I think we need to know test input values before we have any way to test without guessing.